# Ресайз картинок в папке средствами php

Tags: php, изображения

Есть в папке множество картинок. Они не квадратные. Задача - сделать их квадратными по следующему принципу:
Если одна сторона больше другой, то по короткой стороне добавить белые поля по бокам, чтобы стороны стали равны.
Гугление дало мне только возможность обрезки фото под квадрат, но это не то, что я хочу.
Спасибо!

Comment: Пример вашего кода в студию.

Comment: Плохо вы гуглете: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#pad